# Hello world nodejs GAE deploy fails

Tags: google-app-engine

Seems like enabling the appengineflex fails for some reason. I have tried to enable through the console without much luck.

```
descriptor:      [/Users/benflowers/Projects/sample/nodejs-docs-samples/appengine/hello-world/app.yaml]
source:          [/Users/benflowers/Projects/sample/nodejs-docs-samples/appengine/hello-world]
target project:  [sample]
target service:  [default]
target version:  [20170825t201122]
target url:      [https://sample.appspot.com]


Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  y

Enabling service appengineflex.googleapis.com on project candidate-careers...
Waiting for async operation operations/projectSettings.612b02fb-4605-405e-8b07-ecda7aacc2c5 to complete...
```

Comment: I'm going to file an internal bug to have this looked into. Do you get any error after the "Waiting for async operation"?

Comment: Just that it responded with a Failure..

Comment: Same situation here. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope - it just started working again the next day :/

Answer (score 0):

It took about 30 minutes for me before the deploy command worked. I guess it's just some sort of provisioning delay.